# Local Notification Sash Color in WatchOS

Tags: swiftui, notifications, watchos

I'm trying to change the sash color of a local notification in my WatchKit app:

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

class myHostingController: WKUserNotificationHostingController<NotificationView> {
    let sashColor = sashColor
}

func addNotification() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let sashColor = myHostingController.sashColor
    
    let addRequest = {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Title content"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        sashColor?.foregroundColor(.blue)
        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)  
    }
```

I get the error message

> Result of call to 'foregroundColor' is unused

I can't figure out how to call `sashColor`.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Customizing the sash color should be possible according to the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/wkusernotificationhostingcontroller/sashcolor?changes=latest_beta

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/system-experiences/notifications

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am also not able to figure out how to configure sashColor on the notification.

Comment: @gohnjanotis: No, I haven't figured out the answer, but will post it if I do.

Comment: Thank you. I actually had a related question that I posted with an example project here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74338390/title-and-sashcolor-not-appearing-on-customized-long-look-notification-with-wkus

Comment: @gohnjanotis: Thanks for the link to your question - I'll monitor it for responses.